Can a figure made in skin modifier be parented to a rig?
Working in Blender 3.6. I have been experimenting with simple figures created with the skin modifier. Not satisfied with the automatic rig that is generated in the skin modifier, I tried to parent it to a standard bone rig. Parenting did not work. Just wanting to double check that rather than doing something wrong in the parenting process, one can't parent a modifier to a bone. Correct? Thanks!

There's a complete tutorial from Joey Carlino here which includes using the skin modifier armature, but I guess the best way would be to apply the modifier when you're happy with your model and then rig the resulting mesh in the normal way.

Hi, thank you so much for the help! I actually have watched that video several times (slowed down and following every step). Like many well mad Blender videos there are significant gaps in the procedures that can lead to lots of frustration. But your suggestion to apply modifier at end of process makes sense and one I hadn't thought of. Again, so grateful to you and the community here for the support you provide. Many thanks!
